# Oracle 12.2 binary XML and SAX Parser

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, saxparser, binary-xml

I am using SAX Parser to parse the xml type data.

Currently my Java program is reading the data(XMLTYPE) from oracle database(11.2), without writing the data to file, the inputs are passed to sax parser as Input Source.

```
while (orset.next()) {

Reader reader = new BufferedReader(orset.getCharacterStream("xmlrecord"));
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);

sp.parse(is, handler);

}
```

Now the Database team wants to migrate the database from 11.2 to 12.2 binary xml type.

Hence the data format will be changed to binary xml. Kindly assist how to retrieve the binary xml using java and then calling the sax parser.

Also is there a way in oracle to find whether a table is binary XML ?

Comment: Did you try already? I think Binary XML is just the way how Oracle stores the XML internally. But nothing should change on your side when you read or insert the XML data.

Comment: Thanks ! Here i am retrieving the data using `orset.getCharacterStream("xmlrecord")`. In this case only the partial output is retrieved not the entire row.